# error when bootstrapped

Tags: alphanet

I'm running on alphanet.  Went into the alphanet shell.

ran `tezos-client bootstrapped` and get this response:

```
Current head: BL4U2gV1XbRS (timestamp: 2019-03-12T02:13:28Z, validation: 2019-05-10T15:59:24Z)
Bootstrapped.
```

it is a couple months behind, but says it is bootstrapped.  I added new peers and have the same problem.

Comment: i was using the `alphanet.sh` client.  I found that `./alphanet.sh restart` fixed it, but it was a day later and I'm not sure if it was the actual solution or not.  Either way, remember to try this.